# Why is my format giving me an error when I try to format an enum to a string?

Tags: c#

I have the following enum:

```
public enum EReferenceKey {
        Accounts             = 1,
        Emails                = 3,
        Phones               = 4
}
```

When my enum variable pk is Accounts and I try to convert this to "01" using

```
var a = pk.ToString("00");
```

it gives me the following exception:

Format String can be only "G", "g", "X", "x", "F", "f", "D" or "d"

Can someone explain what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to cast it to int before attempting that format string. Enum has its own ToString implementation, as such your int format string is not correct.

```
var a = ((int)pk).ToString("00");
```

Answer (score 3):

You're trying to use the format characters for String.Format. Enums are different. Take a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.format.aspx.

You have to get the value and then format. A cast is the easiest way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

Try casting to an `int` before trying to format the enum value:

```
var a = ((int)EReferenceKey.Accounts).ToString("00");
```

That worked for me.